# Authenticate user with AWS COGNITO

Tags: java, authentication, amazon-cognito

I currently have a middle application that goes to certain resource and validate the user/password,

I'm trying to change this validation and make it goes to COGNITO, all examples I have found are badly documented, incomplete and just fragments, or just mentions the redirect from login to aws login and redirect back to your app, as this app lives between others apps, there are no web browser to redirect to,

Is there a way to write a java code to authenticate the user, and receive the token/cookie from some class? I've found there something called Lambda authorizers, but examples are only in phyton and javascript, does this exist in java?